# Nginx + Passenger - Uncaught exception in PassengerServer client thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I've installed Passenger with Nginx for testing here and I keep getting this error after some thousand requests:

```
[ pid=57259 thr=0x40f07780 file=ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:576 time=2010-12-15 14:04:25.876 ]: Uncaught exception in PassengerServer client thread:
   exception: write() failed: Socket is not connected (57)
   backtrace:
     in 'void Client::forwardResponse(Passenger::SessionPtr&, Passenger::FileDescriptor&)' (HelperAgent.cpp:368)
     in 'void Client::handleRequest(Passenger::FileDescriptor&)' (HelperAgent.cpp:502)
     in 'void Client::threadMain()' (HelperAgent.cpp:595)

[ pid=57259 thr=0x40f07080 file=ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:566 time=2010-12-15 14:04:26.416 ]: Couldn't forward the HTTP response back to the HTTP client: It seems the user clicked on the 'Stop' button in his browser.
```

I have 2 servers, and I was running haproxy+apache+mongrel on them, I switched one of them for haproxy+nginx+passenger (haproxy is only a backup for my testing, so I can redirect to the old schema quickly in case of fire).

So I noticed that my passenger dies after this message.
Im using ruby-ee 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5 and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That turns out to be a FreeBSD kernel bug. We're slowly putting more workarounds in the Phusion Passenger codebase to work around this.

Comment: If you could please give us more details about the bug or how you went about finding it, it would be really helpful I believe.

Comment: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=79138 and http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=144061